# Handle readlines response frim console in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I use a function, which takes input and then asks the user in the console a "y/n" question (via readlines()). It runs in the console but shows nothing in the app and interrupts other actions.

I was wondering if there are any ways either to a) respond to this prompt from shiny b) save a specific response to the variable and pass it as a prompt response automatically (unfortunately, the function itself does not have this value as an argument)

Comment: You can write a modal with some select input, or use some packages like [shinysurveys](https://github.com/jdtrat/shinysurveys) to build a form